# Using float / double as a loop variable

Tags: c++, computer-science

Running on a x64 architecture , Visual Studio 2013  Windows 8.1

I am trying to run a loop which uses a float as its loop  variable , the issue is during the increment operation the decimal values are being lost .

Eg :

```
float incrementValue = 360 / 14;
for (float i = 0; i <= 360; i = i + incrementValue)
{
    cout << endl << " I " << i;
}
```

I need the value of i >= 360 . But  it stops at 350 .
Since 360/14 =25.7142857
but looks like the increments are in steps of 25 .
If i do the same thing with any whole number it works fine , this issue is only with any number of the form xx.yyyy

I  tried looking up various  sites on this issue but i was unable to find anything that helps me / answers my questions .

Comment: `360 / 14` will assign `25.0` to your variable. Use `360.0 / 14.0` to assign `25.7142857`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as such, but because of floating-point precision problems, it is anyway a bad idea to use a `for` loop with floating point increment from where I see it. I would rather use a `while`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using floating point values as a loop increment, as long as you are aware of the few things. First, due to precision errors the number of iterations could vary, so you might land up with +-1 than you expected. Second, for the same reason as above, directly testing for equality against a floating point value is not reliable and you should instead test the value is within some 'acceptable' range.

Comment: @Lionel `There is nothing wrong with using floating point values as a loop increment`  They disagree - https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FLP30-C.+Do+not+use+floating-point+variables+as+loop+counters

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ok, "nothing wrong" was perhaps too strong. :) Maybe "it can be used with some consideration" would have been more appropriate.

Comment: Is there *any situation* where one would take floats over ints? You can always convert the int counter to the float.

Comment: Not directly related, but good information on floating point math in programming: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three problems here (two related), all of which are probably contributing.

The first is that floating point comparisons are generally unwise since, while you may *think* you have `360`, it may in fact be `359.999999942`.

The second is that inaccuracies build up over time. Every time you add a number like `0.99` that you *think* is `1`, the error accumulates.

With the values you're using, these errors are likely to stay small but you should be aware of them anyway. If you start processing lots of numbers, you'll find out about the problems pretty quickly.

---

The final, and unrelated, problem is that `360 / 14` is *integer* division, and it will give you an integer result, `25` instead of `25.714285714`.

You can fix that final problem by ensuring one of the values is a float:

```
float incrementValue = float(360) / 14;
```

But that's not going to fix the first two, which *will* bite you at some point.

To fix *that,* you would be better off sticking with integers (for this simple case anyway) and converting to floating point at the latest possible instance:

```
#include<iostream>
int main (void) {
    int incrementValue = 360;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360 * 14; i = i + incrementValue)
        std::cout << " I " << float(i) / 14 << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

which gives you:

```
 I 0
 I 25.7143
 I 51.4286
 I 77.1429
 I 102.857
 I 128.571
 I 154.286
 I 180
 I 205.714
 I 231.429
 I 257.143
 I 282.857
 I 308.571
 I 334.286
 I 360
```

Comment: But a bit ain't one .... While your statment is true, the case here is that he's making integer divission

Comment: Thanks a lot . I just figured the same thing out .  Issue is that i was not casting the values to float . [ (float)360/(float)14 ] . I made this change , it is working fine now

Comment: @rahul, keep the other two issues in mind as well. While they might not get you yet, they will eventually :-) And only _one_ of the numbers needs to be a float so you could save yourself some typing.

Answer (score 3):

`360 / 14` will give you an integer result. Try `360.0 / 14.0`.

Answer (score 2):

It would be hard to get 'i = 360' since 'i = 360.0000001' would fail the test and getting exactly '360' would be tricky. Floating point on computers is hard and full of little gotchas.

It would be better to use integers as much as possible:-

```
int num_steps = 14;

for (int i = 0 ; i <= num_steps ; ++i)
{
  float value = 360.0f * i / num_steps;
  // use value
}
```

Using '<=' in the loop does mean you get a '360' for 'value' because 'i / num_steps' is one. Having said that, you might not get exactly '360.0f' due to floating point errors.

Answer (score 1):

Make the operands from the division float type :

```
 float incrementValue = 360.f / 14.f;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  float incrementValue = (float)360 / 14;
  for (float i = 0; i <= 360; i = i + incrementValue)
  {
      cout << endl << " I " << i;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of iterations, it is not a good idea to use a float to control a loop, because floats are not exact.

In fact, using a float to control any loop is a bad idea, without use of tolerances (which will depend on machien precision) to allow for potential rounding errors.

In this case, you know the number of iterations, so a loop like this would do the trick.

```
int num_steps = 14
float factor = 360.0/num_steps;

for (int i = 0; i < num_steps; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "\nI" << (i*factor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I really want a float in my loop, I change the upper limit to make sure that I have no errors from continual floating point errors.

```
float x_min = 0.;
float x_max = 360.;
int N_steps = 14;
float x_step = (x_max - x_min) / N_steps;

for (float x = x_min; x <= x_max + x_step / 2; x += x_step)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

While this ensures that I get each step correct, the problems with precision can build up if there are a large number of steps. In that case using an integer loop variable and calculating the corresponding float each time. Then I only the floating point error one time as opposed to 14 (or a million) times summed up.