# Rcpp keeps running for a seemingly simple task

Tags: r, rcpp

I've been thinking about it all day and still cannot figure out why this happens. My objective is simple: STEP1, generate a function S(h,p); STEP2, numerically integrate S(h,p) with respect to p by trapezoidal rule and obtain a new function SS(h). I wrote the code and source it by sourceCpp, and it successfully generated two functions S(h,p) and SS(h) in R. But when I tried to test it by calculating SS(1), R just kept running and never gave the result, which is weird because the calculation amount is not that big. Any idea why this would happen？

My code is here:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//generate the first function that gives S(h,p)           
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double S(double h, double p){
  double out=2*(h+p+h*p);
  return out;
}
//generate the second function that gives the numerically integreation of S(h,p) w.r.t p
//[[Rcpp::export]]

double SS(double h){
  double out1=0;
  double sum=0;
  for (int i=0;i<1;i=i+0.01){
    sum=sum+S(h,i);
  }
  out1=0.01/2*(2*sum-S(h,0)-S(h,1));
  return out1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are treating `i` as if it were not an `int` in this statement:

```
for (int i=0;i<1;i=i+0.01){
    sum=sum+S(h,i);
}
```

After each iteration you are attempting to add `0.01` to an integer, which is of course immediately truncated towards 0, meaning that `i` is always equal to zero, and you have an infinite loop. A minimal example highlighting the problem, with a couple of possible solutions:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void bad_loop() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i += 0.01) {
        std::printf("i = %d\n", i);
        Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt();
    }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void good_loop() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        std::printf("i = %d\n", i);
        Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt();
    }
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void good_loop2() {
    for (double j = 0.0; j < 1.0; j += 0.01) {
        std::printf("j = %.2f\n", j);
        Rcpp::checkUserInterrupt();
    }
}
```

---

The first alternative (`good_loop`) is to scale your step size appropriately -- looping from 0 through 99 by 1 takes the same number of iterations as looping from 0 to 0.99 by 0.01. Additionally, you could just use a `double` instead of an `int`, as in `good_loop2`. At any rate, the main takeaway here is that you need to be more careful about choosing your variable types in C++. Unlike R, when you declare `i` to be an `int` *it will be treated like an `int`*, not a floating point number.

Comment: What would the world of StackOverflow be without @nrussell?

Comment: And in other words, _strongly typed languages will still be strongly typed languages_.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, you're too kind. And yes, agreed. I've always been a little bothered by R's eagerness to convert integers to numerics, but you can't have everything I guess...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! You really made my day. I guess sometimes you just cannot find out the bug by yourself even if it's so obvious!

Answer (score 0):

As @nrussell pointed out very expertly, there is an issue with treating `i` as an `int` when the type held is a `double`. The goal of posting this answer is to stress the need to avoid using a `double` or `float` as a loop incrementer. I've opted to post it as an answer instead of a comment for readability.

Please note, the loop increment should ***not*** ever be given as a `double` or a `float` due to precision issues. e.g. it is hard to get `i = .99` since `i = 0.981111111` et cetera...

Instead, I would opt to have the loop be processed as an `int` and convert it to a `double` / `float` as soon as possible, e.g.

```
for (int i=0; i < 100; i++){
    // Make sure to use double division 
    // (e.g. either numerator or denominator is a floating / double) 
    sum += S(h, i/100.0);
}
```

Further notes:

[RcppArmadillo and C++ division issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36986097/rcpparmadillo-and-c-division-issue)

[Using float / double as a loop variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362197/using-float-double-as-a-loop-variable)